# Strange error in PLSQL script

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a strange error on this pl/sql script

'PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error'
in the is_prime function

```
if((nr mod it) = 0)
HERE->then
        return cast(0 as int);
end if;
```

I can't figure out what I did wrong, because I pass only int's to is_prime and I have declared only a int in is_prime...

```
set serveroutput on;

drop table exresult;
create table exresult(AA int,BB int);

create or replace function is_prime(nr in int) return int is
  it int := 0;
begin
  for it in 2..floor(sqrt(nr)) loop
    if((nr mod it) = 0)
      then
        return cast(0 as int);
    end if;
  end loop;
  return cast(1 as int);
end is_prime;
/

create or replace function sum_digits(nr in int) return int is
  summ int := 0;
  tmp int := nr;
begin
  loop
    summ := summ + (tmp mod 10);
    tmp := floor(tmp / 10);
    exit when tmp = 0;
  end loop;

  return summ;
end sum_digits;
/

declare
  target constant int := 5;
  nmod int := 0;
  nprm int := 0;
  it   int := 0;
begin
  for it in 1..10000 loop
    nmod := sum_digits(it) mod 10;
    nprm := is_prime(it);
    dbms_output.put_line(it + ',' + nmod + ','  + nprm);
    if(nmod = target)
      then
        insert into exresult select it, nprm from dual;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: What happens if you change e.g. `return cast(0 as int);` to `return 0;` which is all you need?

Comment: nothing changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is actually here:

```
dbms_output.put_line(it + ',' + nmod + ','  + nprm);
```

`+` is not the concatenation operator in PL/SQL, you need `||`:

```
dbms_output.put_line(it || ',' || nmod || ','  || nprm);
```

That's relying on implicit conversion of the `int` values to `varchar2`, which is fine, but more correctly should be:

```
dbms_output.put_line(to_char(it) || ',' || to_char(nmod) || ','  || to_char(nprm));
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to read my code and point this mistake. gotta love at what line oracle points the error

Comment: It will be pointing to a line in the final block of code you ran, not in the whole script.